# How to read async HTTP (servlet3.0) response using ajax or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets, servlet-3.0

I am new to javascript/ajax development.
In my application I am using push servelt3.0 at server side while client is ajax to read push message(partial response).
Server continuously push message over ServletOutputStream but at client side I am using ajax to read async http response unlike reading steam in java.
I am getting appended response every time

**ajax code:**

```
var a;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// If the browser if IE7+[or]Firefox[or]Chrome[or]Opera[or]Safari
      a=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
   else
    {//If browser is IE6, IE5
      a=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

a.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  console.log("a.readyState: " + a.readyState + " response is : " + a.response);
  if (a.readyState==4 && a.status==200)
  {
    console.log("state 4 response is : " + a.response);
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=a.responseText;
  }
}
a.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/Servlet3Demo/AsyncLongRunningServlet?time=12000",true);
//a.multipart = true; 
a.overrideMimeType("Transfer-Encoding: chunked");
//a.overrideMimeType("text/plain");
a.send();
}
```

**and the Response is:**

```
a.readyState: 3 response is : Fri Jan 30 11:40:45 IST 2015 ajaxTestPc.html:92
a.readyState: 3 response is : Fri Jan 30 11:40:45 IST 2015Fri Jan 30 11:40:46 IST 2015 ajaxTestPc.html:92
a.readyState: 3 response is : Fri Jan 30 11:40:45 IST 2015Fri Jan 30 11:40:46 IST 2015Fri Jan 30 11:40:47 IST 2015
```

I want to read it like java stream.

Please suggest.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Hey i do not know my answer will match to your requirement but rather than using javascript why you are ont using jQuery for ajax as it is easy to use and very well written short lines of code such as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
      data:'whatever data you want to use to send on url',
      type:'post / get',
      async: true,
      success: function(){
          // whatever on success you want to write
      },
      error: function(){
         // on ajax fail any message
      }
   })
})
```

Like this there are many options for ajax those can be [read here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)